# What do I need to add to my web request for GCP Cloud Function Security?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, http-headers, google-cloud-functions

My HTTP Cloud Function is working fine, but it is public. After testing it out I used the GCP console to restrict it to a particular user (ie my own Google account) and, as I expected, I get 403 when I send requests to it. This is good. But I don't know what I need to add to my request for it to get past Google's security. I assume it wants to check a header for a token and verify it against the IAM, but I haven't found any examples yet.

There's a lot of information about using Cloudflare for this, and also someone has done some clever work building an OAuth check inside their cloud function. But clearly Google is already doing a security check for me (this may be new functionality) and I would rather use that than build my own. To be specific then, I went into the permissions section of my Cloud Function and added a member to the 'Cloud Functions Invoker' role. I can add AllUsers as a member and the CF becomes public, take it out and I'm back to 403 responses. So the security is definitely working. I just need a way to identify the caller.

Does anyone know how to add the right keys or whatever to the request?

Comment: Cloud Function requires a Google OAuth Identity Token for authorization. Any modern Google OAuth library provides this. The HTTP header must be `authorization: bearer <id-token>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more reading and I found the answer [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating)

The answer is that CFs are, indeed, doing OAuth so my request needs to look something like this:

```
curl https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME \
```

-H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"

That's using the gcloud command to pull the JWT down and put it in the header. To actually make it work I needed to create a service account and download its key (to the file referred to below). I then added that to the CF (in permissions) and then used

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=sa-cf.json
```

to make that my currently active account so that the token printed was for that account. Beware when doing this because the tokens quickly expire so if you're pasting them into Postman (as I was) it won't work if you leave it any time before sending the request.

Hope this helps someone else.